# llvm : CallGraphNode giving incorrect function Name

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, call-graph

I am trying to traverse the call graph in llvm. Once I get a node in the call graph, I am trying to print the function name corresponding to that call graph node as well as the number of references.

Results: 
1)The function name is always an empty string.
2)The number of references is always a random number.
3)Also the called functions names are also an empty string.

Code:
bool runOnModule(llvm::Module &M) override
{

```
    CallGraph cg = CallGraph(M);
    cg.dump();// this is correct. It is printing the expected the call graph

    for ( CallGraph::const_iterator itr = cg.begin(), ie = cg.end() ; itr != ie; itr++)
    {
       if (itr->second != nullptr)
       {
            itr->second->dump();
            errs()<<"-----------CGN---------\n";
            CallGraphNode *cgn = itr->second.get();



            if(const Function* fptr = cgn->getFunction())
            {
                errs()<<"Number of references are"<<cgn->getNumReferences()<<"\n";

                errs()<<fptr->getName()<<"\n";


                if(cgn->operator[](0) != nullptr)
                {

                    if(cgn->operator[](0)->getFunction() != nullptr)
                    {
                        errs()<<cgn->operator[](0)->getFunction()->getName()<<"\n";
                    }

                 }
              }
         }
   }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding -DNDEBUG compilation flag. I had the same problem and it helped.
If you are using cmake, you can add following line to CMakeLists file:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DNDEBUG")
```

Comment: Thank you so much..It solved my problem. Where did you find this?

Comment: I learned this from my supervisor :) As far as I understand you need to compile your sources with this flag to be compatible with llvm. This flag basically disables asserts. If you use llvm built from sources, you won't need this.

Comment: But I am using llvm built from sources itself...:)

Comment: Might be that we had different compilation flags. I had an example of CallGraph which worked fine with llvm compiled from sources. But when I tried to run this example in another machine with installed llvm, got this same issue.

Comment: I didn't need this flag, I compiled the app using this command `LLVM_6.0/bin/clang -O0 -c -emit-llvm test_cg.c`
However, the last part of the procedure leads to error. Specifically, the code in the scope of this conditional statement `if(cgn->operator[](0) != nullptr)`. Even after compiling with that flag `-DNDEBUG`, still I'm receiving the same error.